# Setting user avatar in specific size, without breaking layout

Tags: php, html, css, user-interface

I want to make an single folder with user's avatar showing their small avatar (resized) and their big avatar (in their normal size). This is my code.

```
<span class="prfil-img"><img src="images/avatarsmall/<?php echo $id ?>.jpg" alt=""> </span> 


<div class="text-center vd_info-parent"> <img alt="example image" src="https://imgur.com/I80W1Q0.png"> </div>
```

The text-center   div  is big avatar, and I will change it with echo later, but, I can't manage to modify small avatar's size, only if I upload it 60x60, becaus if i set it manually with height  it shows in another place.

ex

```
<span class="prfil-img"><img src="images/avatarsmall/<?php echo $id ?>.jpg" alt="" height="60" width="60"> </span>
```

this is how it looks with height and width option,

[image]

This is how it looks if i upload it manually with 60x60 size :

[image]

[How it looks now without resize, its manually uploaded with 60x60, so it sets the big avatar too on 60x60](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odtUz.png)

[How should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HOu9.png)

Comment: try `height:auto` in images

Comment: you can set the css for image as: `width:60px; height:60px; object-fit:cover;`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I modified height:40% so it won't depend by the size of avatars.